# Nuxt API on Vercel with error "require() of ES Module is not supported", but I'm not using it

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js, vercel

Well, the title says it all.

I'm trying to build an app using nuxt v2 and deploy it on Vercel. This app will have some routes where I use express (code below), on local, everything works well, but when I deploy on Vercel, it says:

```
RequestId: 114b59a0-d9b3-4ca3-89ef-5703822b9375 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
2022-09-27T17:16:24.924Z    undefined   ERROR   Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /var/task/node_modules/got/dist/source/index.js from /var/task/api/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /var/task/node_modules/got/dist/source/index.js in /var/task/api/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/api/index.js:8:35)
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at async getListener (/var/task/___vc/__launcher.js:37:11) {
    code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
  }
RequestId: 96cd13b3-0e95-4f78-b07c-eeb36593faab Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

The issue is: I'm not using require on my routes, I'm using import.

My code:

**vercel.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "api/**/*.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": ["api/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api/index'
  ],
}
```

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express()

app.get("/getPlayerProfileInfos", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    userName: 'Steam_User',
    profileUrl: 'https://store.steampowered.com/',
    userProfilePic: 'https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/123.jpg',
    profileCreated: 1234567890,
    countryCode: 'BR'
  });
})

app.get("/getPlayerGames", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    gameList: [
      {
        "appid": 92,
        "name": "Codename Gordon",
        "playtime_forever": 0,
        "achievements": { "total": 20, "achieved": 8 },
        "price": { "actual": 80, "lowest": 13 }
      },
    ],
    totalGames: 20,
    totalGamesPlayed: 10,
    gamesPlatined: 10,
    totalHoursPlayed: 10,
    accountValue: 10,
    lowestAccountValue: 10
  });
})

export default {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

Comment: What is your locale version of Node + one on Vercel? Maybe an old package only written as ES5?

Comment: @kissu both my and vercel Node version is 16.x
I haven't installed anything but the nuxt dependencies plus express